# How to count whether a date is within two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, count, inner-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like the following:

| Account # | Open Date | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2018 | 04/04/2019 |
| 234 | 01/03/2018 | 03/04/2018 |

I'm trying to create a Table that counts open accounts at the end of the year that looks like the following:

| Year | End of Year Date | # of Open Accounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 12/31/2018 | 1 |

I also have a table with a canonical date that's just a giant table full of dates.  There are many accounts with many open and close dates.  Open dates as early as 2001 and close dates up to and including today.  An account could only have an open date and not a close date - in which case it would be counted as open for that year.

What is a good way to achieve this using SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: where `cast('20181231' as date) between <opendate> and <closedate>`

Comment: What does the *table with a canonical date* look like?

Comment: You want to count only accounts that were specifically opened in 2018 but don't have a close date?

Comment: Canonical Date table has a record for every date from 2000-2025 and has Year, Month, Day of Week, Day of Month, Week of Year, Day of Year etc.

Comment: @PYB accounts that are open status as of the end of the year, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select v.year, v.eoy_date, count(*)
from (values ('2018', date '2018-12-31') as v(year, eoy_date) left join
     t
     on open_date <= v.eoy_date and close_date > v.eoy_date
group by v.year, v.eoy_date;
```

Comment: It needs to be variable beyond 2018.  We would see dates from year 2000 through today.   An account could be opened in 2018 and have a null close date ... in which case it would be counted for 2018 and 2019.

Comment: @MagicalOrange . . . Just add more rows in the `values()` derived table constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the canonical date table and aggregate:

```
select d.year, d.end_of_year_date, count(distinct t.account#) as cnt_open_accounts
from (
    select d.*, max(d.date) over(partition by d.year) as end_of_year_date
    from canonicaldate d
) d
inner join mytable t on d.date between t.open_date and t.close_date
group by d.year, d.end_of_year_date
```